# Send a simple POST request from Quarkus/Java

Tags: java, post, request, quarkus

I want to send a simple POST request to another application to trigger some action there.

I have a quarkus project and want to send the request from inside my CreateEntryHandler - is this possible in a simple way? Or do I need to add something like Apache Httpclient to my project? Does it make sense in combination with quarkus?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The other application, I assume has an API Endpoint?

Lets state that the API endpoint you are trying to call in the other app is:

**POST** `/v1/helloworld`

From your Quarkus Application, you will have to do the following:

- Register a RestClient *As a Service
- Specify the Service information in your configuration properties
- Inject and use this Service

--- In your current Application ---

Pay close attention to the package name.  IT has to match exactly in your application.properties file.

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
package com.helloworld.services

@Path("/v1")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface HelloWorldService{

    @POST
    @Path("/helloworld")
    Response callHeloWorld(HelloWorldPojo payloadToSend);
}
```

//Notice that we are not including the `/v1` in the `mp-rest/url`, why? Because it is included in the `@RestClient` path.

Update your **application.properties** to include the following:

```
com.helloworld.services.HelloWorldService/mp-rest/url=https://yourOtherApplication.com/API
```

--- Your HelloWorldPojo which you will send as payload

**HelloWorldProjo.java**

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name"})
public class HelloWorldProjo{

  private long id;
  private String name;

  //Setters
  //Getters

}
```

In another service where you actually want to use this:

**ServiceWhichCallsYourOtherAPI.java**

```
@RequestScoped
public class ServiceWhichCallsYourOtherAPI{


    @Inject
    @RestClient
    HelloWorldService helloWorldService;



    public void methodA(){

         HelloWorldPojo payloadToSend = new HelloWorldPojo();
         payloadToSend.setId(123);
         payloadToSend.setName("whee");

         helloWorldService.callHelloWorld(payloadToSend);

   } 

}
```

The POST request will then go to https://yourOtherApplication.com/API/v1/helloworld

The json will look like:

```
{
  "id":123,
  "name":"whee"
}
```

Really great read: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client

Comment: Hey buddy, first of all thank you!! This one really helps me out. To be honest I am quite noob in quarkus - @RegisterRestClient seems not to be recognized, what package do I need? I added org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client to my pom.xml but it doesn't seem to help. Any idea? Thanks again :)

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: Fixed! If you do not mind: How can I add some simple JSON to this POST request? [Sorry for chatting here]

Comment: I updated the method to take in a Payload Object.  Simple one. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Do you mind adding in which files the code snippets belong? I was confused about the HelloWorldPojo. Besides that huge THANK YOU buddy!!

Comment: done @RNH Do update me if you get it working :),

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - nice update. Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot my friend :)

Comment: What if the URL is unknown? you load the URL from some object to to send request, assuming all the URLs accept the same request format? how to make the rest client accept a specific URL every time?

Comment: @Mr.Cat You could use RestClientBuilder  See https://wordpress.com/post/jcompetence.com/598

https://github.com/smustafa/quarkus-dynamic-microprofile-path

Comment: https://jcompetence.com/2021/09/27/microprofile-dynamic-baseuri-rest-client/

Comment: If this is simple...

Comment: The property should now be:  
`quarkus.rest-client."com.helloworld.services.HelloWorldService".url="https://yourOtherApplication.com/API"`