# Send a simple GET request from Quarkus/Java

Tags: java, get, request, quarkus

I want to send a DTO from one quarkus application to another. I am using quarkus as framework.
I am looking for something similar to this
[Send a simple POST request from Quarkus/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347707/send-a-simple-post-request-from-quarkus-java)

This is for POST how do I implement what JCompetence is doing in the above post's answer using GET.

I am very new to quarkus and REST.
What will be my files in both the projects?

 What is the flow of your code when using REST.

A very simple implementation/demonstration of how to send a DTO from one application will be very helpful.
Thank you in advance. It will help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abdullah Chaudhry although is possible to send a body (your DTO) in a GET request, I believe it's not recommended. [This post - HTTP GET with request body - talks about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/11110455). But if you want to do this anyway, the ideia is exacly the same as the POST example you gave. You only need to change from `POST` to `GET`.

But, if you're talking about returning a DTO on the body of a GET response, I guess is OK.

Below I put one example using the Quarkus `2.11.1.Final` version.

This example shows how to send a GET with a body and how to answer a GET with another body.

You can find help on these Quarkus guides:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client
- https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive

## DTO

These classes will exist on the Server and Client sides, they will be your DTOs in this example:

```java
public class Account {
    public double balance;
}
```

```java
public class BankClient {
    public int age;
    public String name;
}
```

## Server side

#### pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

#### resource

```java
@Path("/client")
public class ClientResource {
    @Path("/account")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAccount(BankClient bankClient) {
        var account = new Account();
        account.balance = 123.45;
        return Response.status(200).entity(account).build();
    }
}
```

## Client side

#### pom.xml

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

#### application.properties

```
quarkus.rest-client.client-api.url=http://localhost:8080
quarkus.rest-client.client-api.scope=javax.inject.Singleton
```

#### Rest client service

```java
package org.acme;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Path("/client")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="client-api")
public interface ClientService {

    @Path("/account")
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Account getByBankClient(BankClient bankClient);

}
```

#### Tester

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;
@Path("/test")
public class ClientResource {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    ClientService clientService;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeAccount() {

        var bankClient = new BankClient();
        bankClient.age = 30;
        bankClient.name = "John";

        var account = clientService.getByBankClient(bankClient);

        return Response.status(200).entity(account).build();
    }
}
```

### Executing the test

1. Start the Server side application
2. Start the Client side application
3. Execute the `/test` of the Client side, for example with:

```bash
$ curl --verbose http://localhost:8090/test
```

The response should be:

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8090...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8090 (#0)
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8090
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 18
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"balance":123.45}
```