# This method requires a body instead of a semicolon, Java Quarkus post request, and interface does not have the @RegisterRestClient

Tags: java, rest, post, quarkus, jsonb

Trying to send a post request in quarkus simple without any configs, as referred in the official docs [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive#async-support)

And referred in this StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347707/send-a-simple-post-request-from-quarkus-java) as well.

I just did added the extension `quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jsonb` and this straight forward snippet:

```
package org.offerService.infrastructure;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.LeadsService.contract.offerDto.OfferDto;
import org.LeadsService.contract.reponseType.responseTypeOffer.ResponseCreateOffer;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Path("/offer")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "offer-api")
public class OffersRestClientService {

    @POST
    @Path("/createOffer")
    CompletionStage<ResponseCreateOffer> createOffer(OfferDto offer);
}
```

and in the application properties I'm refering to that endpoint:

> quarkus.rest-client.offer-api.url=localhost:8082

Now the error message I get a warning when I try to Inject this service anywhere:

```
The corresponding org.OfferService.infrastructure.OfferRestClientService interface does not have the @RegisterRestClient annotation. The field offerRestClient will not be injected as a CDI bean.microprofile-restclient
```

And in the service itself the same file I shared I get an error in here exactly `createOffer(OfferDto offer);`  ( pre-last line ) says

```
The method createOffer(OfferDto) from the type OfferRestClientService is not visible Java(67108965)
```

so the problem here is that it doesn't recognize `@RegisterRestClient` though it's imported properly

Comment: class vs interface

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to inject the service into another class?

Comment: Should OffersRestClientService be a interface instead of a class?

Comment: Yes the problem is solved Thanks a lot, class vs interface @ScaryWombat you can post it as an answer and I will confirm it